# How to submit form within submit handler?

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a confirm message that would popup when user tries to submit a form. I came up with the following, but this looks like a hack to me.

```
$('#someform').submit(function () {
  var form = $(this);
  //a hack so that this handler does not fire again, see below
  if (form.attr('data-confirm') == 'disabled') {
    return true;
  }

  showConfirmPopup({
    message: "Are you sure?",
    success: function () {

      form.attr('data-confirm', 'disabled');
      form.submit();

      hideConfirmPopup();
    }
  });

  return false;
})
```

});

So when user submits form this handler will catch the event and prevent, display popup and prevent form submit (by returning `false`). When user confirms, success handler will all form submit method and our handler will fire again, but this time it will return `true` and form will be submitted.

Can this be achived without writing the `data-confirm` attribute?

Comment: I'd probably use a variable rather than an attribute, but it's the same idea.

Comment: I would go for a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, you could simply [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) your `submit` handler within your success callback, and then re-submit the form. Something like this should do the trick:

```
...
success: function () {
    hideConfirmPopup();
    form.unbind('submit').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with a simple:

```
$('#someform').submit(function () {
  var submitForm = false;
  showConfirmPopup({
    message: "Are you sure?",
    success: function () {
      submitForm = true;
      hideConfirmPopup();
    });
  return submitForm;
});
```

I'm assuming that `showConfirmPopup` is synchronous.